# Checking the status of a thread that is controlling a timer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services, timer

I'm running a thread in a Windows Service periodically using a Threading.Timer like so:

```
private Timer _timer;

public void Start()
{
    _timer = new Timer(MainLoop, null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void MainLoop(object state)
{
    // Do something and then tell Timer to wait for a second
    _timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
}

public void Stop()
{
    _timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

My problem is that I want the Windows Service to be able to monitor the thread that the loop is running in and do something if it is found to have stopped.

Previously I was using a Thread.Sleep instead of a Timer and that meant that everything ran in a single Thread rather than individual threads in the thread pool and I could query the ThreadState of the Thread. Now that I am using a Timer the ThreadState is "Stopped" as the Thread stops once the Timer has been started.

So what is the best way for me to confirm that the thread is still running when using a Threading.Timer?

Comment: The loop isn't running on any particular thread. When the timer period elapses, `MainLoop` will execute on the first available thread pool thread. If there are other things going on in your program, `MainLoop` will very likely execute on a different thread the next time it's called. You can't monitor the thread. The answer below that suggests using a last run time is probably the easiest way to get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: What kind of work does the main loop spend most of its time  doing? Process files? Poll database? Handle network requests? Perform a computational task? And what do you want to do if the loop is not running?

Comment: @Jason the main loop is polling the database. I have two of these services running on different servers, one active and one passive. The passive polls the active service over TCP and if it finds that the loop has stopped then it should take over as the active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a try-finally block around the contents `MainLoop` to guarentee that the timer always gets restarted.

```
private void MainLoop(object state)
{
  try
  {
    // Do something and then tell Timer to wait for a second
  }
  finally
  {
    _timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
  }
}
```

If you still think you need to monitor the execution of this method you could keep track of the last time the method started.

```
private void MainLoop(object state)
{
  _lastRunTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
  try
  {
    // Do something and then tell Timer to wait for a second
  }
  finally
  {
    _timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
  }
}
```

You could then use `_lastRunTime` and compare it to the current time to see if the execution of `MainLoop` got hung up or the timer (for some obscure reason) did not restart.

Comment: It stupidly hadn't occurred to me to wrap the whole thing in a try...catch.

Answer (score 2):

Have the thread update some value that is visible to the Windows Service, and if the value is not updated, you know the thread has stopped. I dont know of any other way of monitoring the timer

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different approach, creating your own thread and using a callback to signal that the thread is done. The callback passes back a result that your main thread uses to decide what to do. You don't even need a timer to do this, although you can use one to cause your worker to fire on an interval.

Here's an example that uses a WaitHandle to signal the supervisor that it's done.

```
class Supervisor
{
    EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public bool Success { get; set; }

    // launch worker thread and wait for result
    public void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => { new Worker(new DoneDelegate(WorkerDone)).DoWork(); });
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
            waitHandle.WaitOne(); // wait for worker to finish
            if (!Success) break; // handle error here
        }
    }

    // callback for worker to report result
    public void WorkerDone(bool successArg)
    {
        Success = successArg;
        // wake up supervisor
        waitHandle.Set();
    }
}

public delegate void DoneDelegate(bool successArg);
class Worker
{
    public DoneDelegate Done { get; set; }
    public Worker(DoneDelegate doneArg)
    {
        Done = doneArg;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        // simulate work and exception
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        try
        {
            int i = 10 / (1 - new Random().Next(5));
            Done(true);
        }
        catch
        {
            Done(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to go with Brian's answer because it is simpler but thanks a lot.